# How to wrap an inner div with relative position?

Tags: css

I have an outer and inner box with position set to relative. What i want should look like this:

[image]

The code is:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.outerbox {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 30px;
  top: 50px;
  background: orange;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.innerbox {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top:100px;
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outerbox">
    <div class="innerbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is it possible to get a similar result with `margin:0` and changing only `top` and `left` values in `innerbox`?

With this style the outer div no more wraps the inner box:

**CSS**

```
.innerbox {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    background: green;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

[image]

Thank you.

*** Update ***

I would like to add that i don't want to fix the height of the outer box. Thanks.

Comment: what is the purpose behind this? you can do it with margin, then what's the issue?

Comment: then you need to add fixed height width for outer div

Comment: yes but why? we don't simply decide to use something because we may *thinhk* that something else is not good. Why you think you will not missuse top/left here? all depend on your need. So what is the purpose behind this? what you want to achieve? why not margin? and why top/left?

Comment: sorry but this is a community website, you cannot oblige persons to not comment or answer. You are free to post a question and I am free to comment/answer. It's not about *you* and *me* it's about the question. I am commenting the content of the question, I am not commenting about *you* so don't take this personnally.

Comment: and you added this `I would like to add that i don't want to fix the height of the outer box.` and I will ask you why? you are adding requirements without explaining why, so we should ask *why* if you want us to give accurate answers. As a side note, I can only downvote once and you got 2 downvotes so it's not my downvoteS and you have not way to know if I am one of the downvoters

Comment: _“Is it possible to get a similar result with margin:0 and changing only top and left values in innerbox?”_ - not really. Relative positioning moves an element from it’s “default” position that it would normally have - but it keeps the original space it would have required reserved, it does not make it “take” the space at the position it was moved _to_. So while you can move the inner element to the place you want it, it will not make the outer element “grow” accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get a similar result with margin:0 and changing only top and left values in innerbox?

Not really.

Relative positioning moves an element from it’s “default” position that it would normally have - but it keeps the *original* space it would have required reserved, it does not make it “take” the space at the position it was moved *to*. So while you can move the inner element to the place you want it, it will not make the outer element “grow” accordingly.

> I don't want ("mis")use margin for positioning the inner div

Don’t worry about the “semantics of CSS” too much here … There is often more than one way to achieve a desired optical result, and seldom one way is “wrong” and the other one “right”.

As long as the solution you have achieves what you want, and is not hindered by other restrictions - use it!

Answer (score 0):

When the outerbox has `position: relative` you can use `position: absolute` for the `.innerbox` so you can give dimensions to the `.outerbox` (width and height) and you can use `top` and `left` to position the inner rectangle on every position you want...

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.outerbox {
  position: relative;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  left: 30px;
  top: 50px;
  background: orange;
  border: 2px solid red;
  
}

.innerbox {
  position: absolute;
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  left:98px;
  top:48px;
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outerbox">
    <div class="innerbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.outerbox {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 30px;
  top: 50px;
  background: orange;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
}


.innerbox {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
  /*left: 100px;
    top: 100px; */
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background: green;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerbox">
    <div class="innerbox">
    </div>
  </div>
```